# Specify output directory for htlatex

Tags: tex4ht, output

I would like to know how I can specifiy the output directory for the html/css generated by htlatex.

My call is as follows:

```
htlatex main.tex
```

The files are generated in the same directory where main.tex is located. But I would rather like to write it to a folder named html contained in the current directory (./html).

I read about adding `"" "-d/mypath/"` args but it didn't work out.

Can someone help me? I also have some problems to get documentation as calling htlatex with `-h` or `--help` doesn't work out.

http://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html was not useful either.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 13):

A little investigation reveals that `htlatex` is indeed a `sh` script file, at least in my system:

```sh
$ which htlatex
/usr/texbin/htlatex
$ file /usr/texbin/htlatex
/usr/texbin/htlatex: symbolic link to `../../texmf-dist/scripts/tex4ht/htlatex.sh'
```

And the contents of that script are:

```sh
$ cat /usr/texbin/htlatex
#!/bin/sh
        latex $5 '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode '$2'.a.b.c.\input ' $1
        latex $5 '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode '$2'.a.b.c.\input ' $1
        latex $5 '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode '$2'.a.b.c.\input ' $1
        tex4ht -f/$1  -i~/tex4ht.dir/texmf/tex4ht/ht-fonts/$3
        t4ht -f/$1 $4 ## -d~/WWW/temp/ -m644
```

So it consists of a sequence of calls to `latex`, `tex4ht` and finally `t4ht`. Apparently the script expects 5 parameters (`$1` to `$5`) and from their use we can deduce, more or less, their function:

- `$1` is the name of the file containing the `latex` source. It is passed to all the tools in the chain.
- `$2` is part of a parameter passed to a mysterious command `\HCode` defined in place for the `latex` command, and whose mission I didn't try to understand. I will ignore this parameter until someone better equiped than me can discover its function
- `$3` is passed to `tex4ht` as part of the `-i` option, and thus serve to specify a folder for fonts.
- `$4` is passed to `t4ht` so looks like a place where we can specify additional switches for `t4ht`.
- `$5` is passed to latex, so it looks like a place where we can specify additional switches for `latex`.

Using `t4ht --help` we discover that the `-d` option can be used here to specify the destination directory, so I tried:

```sh
$ htlatex Example.tex "" "" -d/tmp/
```

And it worked. The result goes to `/tmp/`, but note that this affects only to the final step. The first steps still use the current directory, so all intermediate and auxiliary files are still there. I guess you cannot get ride of them with a switch.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. Is there the possibility to add a usage message to this shell script? Shall I make a proposition to tug.org?