# htlatex: customising the build process

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

I'd like to customise the processes used when calling `htlatex`; in particular, I'd like to be able to switch off the conversion of included images into `.png` files.

With the following file, say `mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
Some mathematical content: $y=x$
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

and `myconfig.cfg`

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}
\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta charset="UTF-8" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht
(http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/\string~gurari/TeX4ht/)" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link
         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="\expandafter\csname aa:CssFile\endcsname" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript"\Hnewline
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"\Hnewline
></script>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<style type="text/css">\Hnewline
  .MathJax_MathML {text-indent: 0;}\Hnewline
</style>\Hnewline}}
% margin note
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

when I run

```
 htlatex.exe mwe "myconfig.cfg, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

part of the process converts `example-image-a.eps` to `example-image-a.png`; this is as intended, but not necessary every time I call `htlatex`.

How can I configure my call to `htlatex` so that I can toggle the image conversion step?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62729/specify-output-directory-for-htlatex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Image conversion is executed by the `t4ht` command. It has `-p` option, which can suppress the image generation when the target file exists. You can options to `t4ht` using slightly complicated `htlatex` call:

```
htlatex.exe mwe "myconfig.cfg, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8" " -p"
```

This can be simplified using `make4ht`. Create a build file `mwe.mk4`:

```
if mode == "draft" then
  settings.t4ht_par = "-p"
end
```

The `mode` variable can be set on the command line using `-m` option. The `draft` mode uses only one LaTeX run instead of usual three, so it greatly speeds up the compilation. The equivalent to the `htlatex` call is the following `make4ht` command:

```
make4ht -um draft -c myconfig mwe
```

This is the result:

[image]

Btw, the config file can be simplified as well:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,html5}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript"\Hnewline
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"\Hnewline
></script>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<style type="text/css">\Hnewline
  .MathJax_MathML {text-indent: 0;}\Hnewline
</style>\Hnewline}}
% margin note
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is fantastic! Is there a reference you could provide for documentation so that I could read more about the different modes?

Comment: @cmhughes there is only `draft` mode configured by default, but you can use your own modes in the build files.

Comment: @cmhughes there is a short note on page 6 of make4ht manual

Comment: many thanks. the `htlatex` works as expected, but the `make4ht` command still does the conversion; do I need to alert `make4ht` to `mwe.mk4` in some way?

Comment: The `mk4` file is loaded automatically if it has the same basename as your TeX file. If it doesn't you can use the `-e` option to point to it.